# Importing module that imports another module(s) in Python

Tags: python, import, module

I'm currently trying to rewrite an old app, and becuase first things first, I want to clean up the structure a little bit. I encountered a problem with importing modules, and I've exhausted few options found over the web, so it's time to ask for help.

The relevant structure is:

```
root/
   __init__.py
   app.py
   interface/
      __init__.py
      darkMotive.py
      mainWindow.py
```

app.py

```
import interface.mainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = mainWindow(root)
    title = root.title("app")
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

mainWindow.py

```
import darkMotive
import tkinter as tk

class mainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    [rest of the code]
```

darkMotive.py

```
import tkinter as tk
[other classes definitions]
```

My problem is that when I try to run app.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/x/xxx/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import interface.mainWindow
  File "X:\x\xxx\interface\mainWindow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import darkMotive
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkMotive'
```

But when I run mainWindow.py alone, it works.
What do I do wrong? Could you point me in the right direction? Shouldn't module darkMotive be imported with mainWindow into app.py's namespace?

Comment: Can you try `from interface import darkMotive`?

Comment: @PythonSherpa Adding your snippet to app.py doesn't solve the problem. Even adding it to mainWindow doesn't. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't fit in the comments, but can you try the following?

mainWindow.py

```
from interface import darkMotive
```

app.py

```
from interface.mainWindow import mainWindow
```

You probably want to rename `mainWindow.py`, because it clashes with the class name.

Comment: I've changed class name and added your code - it works. seems like I have to read more about modules, but maybe can point out what was wrong (even roughly)?

Comment: Sure. Your `app.py` is located in root. The `mainWindow.py` and `darkMotive` located in interface. So you are doing `relative` imports. There are plenty of good articles on this, just give it a go.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it. :)